# Where has C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\lxss gone under Windows Fall Creators Update

Tags: development-environment, windows-subsystem-for-linux

A popular development pipeline, and one of the benefits of the Windows Subsystem for linux is to use a Linux based developer toolchain, i.e. gcc etc within WSS and then to access those build artifacts *from* Windows.  In earlier versions of Windows 10 (1703 and earlier), you could access the Windows Subsystem for Linux file system via:

C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\lxss

This allowed you to access 'Linux' files from Windows.

Strictly speaking you were not supposed to modify any files there - but it was useful for read access.

Reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/402#issuecomment-220585695

Under the Fall Creators Update of Windows 10 (1709), this seems to have disappeared.

Where has it gone?  Clearly a workaround is to, as the last stage of the built pipeline copy *out* of Linux into Windows using the `/mnt` mount, but not being access the files *from* windows seems like it must be a problem for many developers.

Comment: This is a question about software used primarily for programming / development.  Seems odd to me that it was closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that in order to support the capability to install several different installations of the Windows Subsystem for Linux, storing the file system in fixed location no longer made sense.

I created a unique file name in the /home/username directory, and then searched for it from Windows.

In my particular case the file system is stored in:

C:\Users\donal\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\username

It seems likely that the location varies on every installation.